# Phoenix App Redirecting to a Different Page in Production

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Here's the relevant controller action:

```
  def create(conn, %{"post" => post_params}) do
    changeset = Post.changeset(%Post{}, post_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, _post} ->
        conn
        |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :thanks))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

In development - this action redirects the user to a thank you page after creating a post. In production; however, it redirects them to `example.com/posts` instead of `example.com/thanks`.

In production the page displays this:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: If you're redirected to `/posts` I suspect that `Repo.insert` returned `{:error, changeset}` and thus your case fell into the second clause, which does not "redirect" you, but just renders the creation form again.
Although, given that it also shows a 500, I guess there's something else that's not working.

Comment: Show the snippet of your router, `:thanks` it's certainly not REST's route - did you added it on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I hadn't created the table in my production database by running `heroku run mix ecto.migrate`. The error was because the post wasn't being created.